# Is there a way to get the wallpaper to "tile" instead of "center"?

Tags: desktop-background

I switch between 2 screens on my laptop: a 1280x1024 monitor and the built-in 1366x768 LCD. I have a 1366x1024 wallpaper I'd like to use, but I want it locked to the top-left corner (like Windows does with a tiled wallpaper).

When I use 'tile' on Ubuntu 11.10 and the image is larger than my screen, it centers it. Is there any way to get it to lock the wallpaper to the top (without stretching it)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best thing you can do is automatically adjust the size such that it forces the tile setting to behave as desired. This can be done with GIMP.

Answer (score 1):

On an old IBM with a resolution of 1024X768.

The wallpaper resolution is 1440X900.

What I did is just a right click on the desktop -> Change background -> Choose fit to screen.

This will center the Wallpaper, however it will also stretch it if they are not the same proportion.